# How to specify a range of valid values in a Java GUI

Tags: java, swing, jslider, jspinner, ui-design

I am creating an IMDB application which displays and organizes movies found on you computer (by looking up the metadata via an IMDB API).

In my search panel I want to give the user the option of looking for movies that were released in a specific range of years (e.g. between 1990 and 2005). Currently I use for this two JSpinners, one for the minimum year and one for the maximum year and use cross validation to check whether `maxYear >= minYear && minYear <= maxYear` However I don't think this is very user-friendly.

What I would like is a JSlider with two knobs, one for min and one for max. Is this possible? Do you have any other ideas on how to make this interface more user-friendly?

Comment: `maxYear >= minYear` means the same as `minYear <= maxYear` so in `maxYear >= minYear && minYear <= maxYear` you are checking same condition twice. Only one condition is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks promising: [Creating a Java Swing range slider](http://ernienotes.wordpress.com/2010/12/27/creating-a-java-swing-range-slider/)

And here's another example that I think came from the old Tame examples: [MThumbSlider](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/ThumbSliderExample2.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You could have two JTextFields, and just let the user type the minimum and maximum years.

Otherwise, two JSpinners is another choice.  Developing a custom component that your users have never seen is not user friendly.

You can cross connect the two JSpinners so that it's impossible for the user to enter a minimum year greater than a maximum year.  I've not done this, so I don't have a code example to show you.

Comment: You just recommended using the exact same thing he said he's actually using :/

Comment: @asermax: The OP said he was checking.  I suggested enforcing.  In other words, programatically changing the minimum year when the maximum year is changed, and vice versa.