# Validating two JSpinners

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jspinner

I have two JSpinners in one GUI:

```
JSpinner spinner1 = new JSpinner(model1); // To select start date
JSpinner spinner2 = new JSpinner(model); // to select end date
```

How can I ensure that the end date is greater than the start date?

for example:

```
Start Date: 07/12/2014
End Date: 10/12/2014
```

The above is valid. But what if the user selects:

```
Start Date: 10/12/2014
End Date: 07/12/2014
```

Which of course is invalid as you cannot end before you start. Is there a way to ensure that the end date will be greater than than the start date?

Comment: When a date in spinner 1 is selected, change the model of spinner two to start at that date.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15687521/how-to-specify-a-range-of-valid-values-in-a-java-gui

Comment: So.. did you manage to solve this given my tip?

Comment: My apologies @Andrew, I haven't had time to implement your suggestion. Though, I am unclear of what you mean, as in 'new SpinnerDateModel' for Spinner2?

Comment: Which part don't you understand?  Be specific.

Comment: Well, as in what do you mean by "change the model"? - As in 'SpinnerModel model = new SpinnerDateModel();'